# KL Divergence on the Sphere

Tags: riemannian-geometry, information-geometry

Given two empirical measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, restricted to the $(n-1)$-dimensional unit sphere $\mathcal{S}^{n-1}$, is there a closed form expression for the (discrete / sample) KL divergence between them, $D(\mu \mathrel{\Vert} \nu)$?